# C++ error: expected identifier before "(" token

Tags: c++

```
int nn1,nn2;
for (int i=1;i<=m;i++) if (A[i]>minim) && (A[i]<maxim) nn1++;
for (int j=1;j<=n;j++) if (B[j]>minim) && (B[j]<maxim) nn2++;
if (nn1>nn2) cout<<"1";
if (nn1<nn2) cout<<"2";
if (nn1=nn2) cout<<"0";

return 0;
}
```

can anybody give me a suggestion please why the compiler shows the error?

Comment: the error appears in the second line

Comment: `if (A[i] > minim && A[i] < maxim) nn1++;` etc,

Comment: Simple syntax error: `if (A[i]>minim) && (A[i]<maxim) nn1++;` should be `if ((A[i]>minim) && (A[i]<maxim)) nn1++;`  Similarly for the next line.

Comment: stupid mistake :D thanks!

Comment: @Andrew Side note:  What is `A` and `B`?  Are they arrays?  If so, how big are they?  The reason why I ask is that loops that try to fake 1-based arrays (such as yours) many times end up writing beyond the bounds of the array.

Comment: @Pixelchemist has the cleaner solution. All 5 of the answers suggesting adding redundant brackets that harm readability is a little surprising. Not to mention the whitespace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In these if statements there are absent external parentheses

```
for (int i=1;i<=m;i++) if (A[i]>minim) && (A[i]<maxim) nn1++;
for (int j=1;j<=n;j++) if (B[j]>minim) && (B[j]<maxim) nn2++;
```

I think that there should be

```
for (int i=1;i<=m;i++) if ( (A[i]>minim) && (A[i]<maxim) ) nn1++;
for (int j=1;j<=n;j++) if ( (B[j]>minim) && (B[j]<maxim) ) nn2++;
```

And the loops look suspeciously. Take into account that array indices start from 0. So for example if you have an array of size `N` then the valid range of indices is `[0, N-1]`

And you forgot to initialize `nn1` and `nn2`.

It seems that you mean the following

```
int nn1 = 0, nn2 = 0;

for ( int i = 0; i < m; i++ ) 
{
    if ( ( A[i] > minim ) && ( A[i] < maxim ) ) nn1++;
}

for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++ ) 
{
    if ( ( B[i] > minim ) && ( B[i] < maxim ) ) nn2++;
}

if ( nn1 > nn2 ) cout << "1";
else if ( nn1 < nn2 ) cout << "2";
else cout << "0";
```

Answer (score 3):

Fix the brackets in if condition. Something like if (condition1 && condition2). I also suggest using curly brackets for every branch condition.

```
for (int i=1;i<=m;i++) {
    if ((A[i]>minim) && (A[i]<maxim)) { 
        nn1++;
    }
}
for (int j=1;j<=n;j++) {
    if ((B[j]>minim) && (B[j]<maxim)) {
        nn2++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Take care of paranthesis when dealing with `ifs`:

```
if ( (B[j]>minim) && (B[j]<maxim) )

   |                              |
   V                              V

 Add these
```

So, your code should be:

```
int nn1,nn2;
for (int i=1;i<=m;i++) if ( (A[i]>minim) && (A[i]<maxim) ) nn1++;
for (int j=1;j<=n;j++) if ( (B[j]>minim) && (B[j]<maxim) ) nn2++;
if (nn1>nn2) cout<<"1";
if (nn1<nn2) cout<<"2";
if (nn1=nn2) cout<<"0";

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Missing parentheses around the whole condition :

```
for (int i=1;i<=m;i++) if((A[i]>minim) && (A[i]<maxim)) nn1++;
//                       ^                            ^
```

Answer (score 2):

You forgot the ( ) in if statement.Try this :

```
int nn1,nn2;
for (int i=1;i<=m;i++) if ((A[i]>minim) && (A[i]<maxim)) nn1++;   //note extra ()
for (int j=1;j<=n;j++) if ((B[j]>minim) && (B[j]<maxim)) nn2++;   //note extra ()
if (nn1>nn2) cout<<"1";
if (nn1<nn2) cout<<"2";
if (nn1=nn2) cout<<"0";
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In C++,there should be a complete "()" after the "if" and what in "()" is the condition.
So,the code you showed is   if(A[i]>minim) && (A[i]minim) && (A[i]